# When will Hazelcast map elements be persisted besides calling the put operation?

Tags: java, hazelcast

I have a hazelcast cluster with 2 nodes and a DB for the persistence. I start the two nodes one after the other. The first node reads the entities from the DB and build the corresponding map (entityMap). After I start the second node, the EntityMapStore.store() method is called (on the 2nd node) regularly for quite a few times.
I am just wondering, how should this happen, because after starting I have not put anything into the map. Or did I do something incorrectly?

The corresponding part of the hazelcast.xml looks like:

```
   <map name="entityMap">
        <backup-count>1</backup-count>
        <map-store enabled="true">
            <class-name>EntityMapStore</class-name>
            <write-delay-seconds>1</write-delay-seconds>
        </map-store>
    </map>
```

Comment: And this also brings up the question as to how data is now balanced. Since the data is stored on a DB, now how is the data distributed? While the data is written through, is there also an in memory copy of it on one node, and a backup copy on another?

Answer (score 4):

No. You are not doing anything wrong. Since you have `write-delay-seconds > 0`, when entries migrates to the second node, `store()` is called for these entries on the second node. This is the current behavior but you might want to [create an issue](http://code.google.com/p/hazelcast/issues/) for this so that Hazelcast team can enhance this behavior by not calling `store()` for the migrated undirty entries.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As you said, if I set write-delay-seconds = 0 on the second node; the store() won't be called on the second node. However, why? I had thought that the store() would still be called after each entity migration.

Comment: Because if write-delay-seconds = 0, it means store() is already called  on the first node. There is no need to call it on the second node. Hazelcast assumes that datastore is centralized (like sql database).